# Angular 6 library module config

Tags: angular, module, angular6, hammer.js

I have a Angular project with several libraries/projects inside. One of these libraries is a custom carousel (which uses hammerjs) that I can re-use within any other library. The problem is want to set config for hammerjs within the carousel module without having to set it in the shell. So that it handles all it own config. It only works if I set it in the shell app.module.ts and not in the carousel.module.ts.

For e.g. I want to set

```
export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  buildHammer(element: HTMLElement) {
    let mc = new Hammer(element, {
      touchAction: 'pan-y',
      recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Pan, { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL }],
      ],
    });
    return mc;
  }
}
```

and

```
providers: [{ provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: MyHammerConfig }]
```

Anyone know how to make any consuming library use the config from the library it is consuming?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's currently a limitation of Angular that event plugins must be created at bootstrap time. In the short term, you can add a provider just for the Hammer gesture config only in app module.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19874

Comment: Thank you, I am doing it that way now. Just using the provider from the carousel in my main app module.

Comment: Is this issue still exists? Can I add the hammermodule on my lazy loading module?